# Add svg to dropdown menu without repeating the svg element

Tags: html, css

I have an svg of right arrow as

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000">
<path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
<path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8-8-8z"/></svg>
```

i need to add this to dropdown items. But without repeating the svg element.

I have tried

```
.arrow_forward::after{
  content:  url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8-8-8z"/></svg>');

}

<li><a href="history.php" class="dropdown-item arrow_forward"><span class="arrow_forward"></span>History</a></li>
```

it is not displaying

Comment: you can use SVG as an image to save this as abc.svg

Answer (score 0):

It is not the right way to add svg to html. Try this below:

```html
    <li>
      <a href="history.php" class="dropdown-item arrow_forward"
        ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000">
          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
          <path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8-8-8z" />
        </svg>
        History</a
      >
    </li>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path

Comment: the problem is that i need to do this almost 20 times in my code.
i didn't want to repeat my code

Comment: It should be possible to use the SVG in a CSS url - we need to find out why that isn't working, not add lots of stuff to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters need encoding as this is to be part of a url.

```css
.arrow_forward::after {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='24px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24px' fill='%23000000'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h24v24H0V0z' fill='none'/%3E%3Cpath d='M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8-8-8z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="history.php" class="dropdown-item arrow_forward"><span class="arrow_forward"></span>History</a></li>
</ul>
```